# Reusable independent timer instance in vue 3

Tags: vuejs3

I have a timer in my App, which I want to use in several components. When I start use it in one component other components get the timeToRetry state from it. How to transform this code to have 2 and more independent timers in different components of one App ?

```
interface State {
  timeToRetry: number;
  timer: ReturnType<typeof setTimeout> | null;
}

const state: State = reactive({
  timeToRetry: 0,
  timer: null,
});

const stopTimer = () => {
  state.timeToRetry = 0;
  if (state.timer) {
    clearTimeout(state.timer);
    state.timer = null;
  }
};

const startTimer = (seconds: number) => {
  stopTimer();

  state.timeToRetry = seconds;

  state.timer = setInterval(() => {
    if (state.timeToRetry > 0) {
      state.timeToRetry--;
    } else {
      stopTimer();
    }
  }, 1000);
};

export default {
  ...toRefs(state),
  startTimer,
  stopTimer,
};
```

Answer (score 2):

You could [wrap it as a class](https://codesandbox.io/p/devbox/goofy-fire-dfhdww?file=%2Fsrc%2Ftimer.ts%3A10%2C19) and create as many instances as you need.

---

Side notes:

- to me, naming is important, so I renamed `timer` to `interval`, as it's the Return of a `setInterval` and named `timeToRetry` to `timer` (other appropriate names being `countdown` or `remainingSeconds`)
- although `clearTimeout` and `clearInterval` are interchangeable in current browser implementations, they are not guaranteed to always work like this, as it's not part of the spec. To make sure you're clearing an interval, you should use `clearInterval`, not `clearTimeout`
- the model you're using is guaranteed not to be accurate ***<sup>1</sup>***; the actual time passed since you call `timer.start(N)` until the countdown reaches `0` will be longer than `N` seconds, because the code does not account for code execution time. In a nutshell, the busier/slower the processor when the code is run, the bigger the delay.
  The errors are normally small (< 0.1%) and can be ignored if accuracy is not paramount in your app ***<sup>2, 3</sup>***.

---

***<sup>1</sup>*** - creating an accurate timer/stopwatch in JavaScript is a complex problem and is outside of current question's scope. If accuracy is important for your use-case, I suggest researching the issue and, should you not find satisfactory solutions, asking a separate question
***<sup>2</sup>*** - counting `N` seconds from a user interaction is not a case where you should concern yourself with time measurement accuracy in JavaScript. But if you wanted to create an accurate actual watch, it would start being inaccurate by more than a second in a matter of hours, if it used the code pattern you're using.
***<sup>3</sup>*** - to exemplify, I've added a method to calculate the actual time difference between mounting and the last timer reaching `0`, which should be `60s`. Typically I get delays of `1-5ms`, with most of them being `2-3ms`. Curiously enough, the JS engine seems to compensate for this effect, at least in Chrome, and often times I see the difference starting at `~5ms` and getting smaller towards the end `~2ms`, which means that given a longer overall interval we might see the delta getting into negative values. Regardless, the main takeaway here is time intervals in JS are not accurate.

---

Also note making the tab inactive will cause the last update to happen when the tab is reactivated (e.g: leaving it inactive for 10 minutes it will wrongly say the actual seconds passed were 600).